# TFS- Add an existing solution to the source contorl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Hy.

I want to readd an existing solution to the source control.
I could remap, and add the solution to the source control again, but when I checked in it writes: there is an existing file on the server and I have to choose between the local and the server item, what is not good, because there were changes on the server and I do not want to overwrite it.

Why does not the automerge work and how am I able to solve this probelm?

Answer (score 0):

If the files on server are checked in and you will add the new ones by overriding the older ones it should make the new ones checked out and when you will try to check them in it will auto-merge.
****BACKUP BEFORE DOING THIS THOUGH****